# Leverage azure app appid appsecret on differet sharepoint tenants

Tags: sharepoint-addin, authentication, provider-hosted-app, azure

I am developing some **api running on azure** function app. 
This api may **connect to different sharepoint** sites ( even on different **tenants** ) and perform certain actions.

Regarding the **api authentication,** I want to create **an Azure app** on a single azure tenant, and register that ***app id*** in each one of the different sharepoint tenant is which the api is going to be used. This way, I dont have to upload the webservice on different tenants etc...

I such thing possible ? what would be the best approach ? thanks

Comment: I was also curious about the same. There some challenges: 1) We have to add a new URL to CORS each time we need to work with a new tenant 2) After we secure our Azure Function with Azure AD (by associating with Client id and tenant ID), how do we "connect" multiple external Office 365 tenant to that original App Registration?  At this point, I know how to connect a single Azure function with a single Office 365 tenant. but I would like to be able to connect a single Azure App with multiple tenants somehow.